Binomial identity involving square binomial coefficient
I want to prove this identity, but I have no idea...
Could someone please post a solution? Thank you.
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{-1/2}{n+k}\binom{n+k}{k}\binom{n}{k}= \binom{-1/2}{n}^2$$
(Maybe -1/2 can be replaced to arbitrary number but I'm not sure)

The MSE guidelines are not in favor of posts that merely state an identity to be proved without giving context or motivation. Please edit and show your work on the question.

We have the identity for polynomials in $x$ which is
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {x\choose n+k} {n+k\choose k} {n\choose k}
= {x\choose n}^2.$$
We get for the first two binomial coefficients,
$$\frac{x^{\underline{n+k}}}{(n+k)!} \frac{(n+k)!}{n!\times k!}
= \frac{x^{\underline{n}}}{n!} \frac{(x-n)^{\underline{k}}}{k!}
= {x\choose n} {x-n\choose k}.$$
We have one factor. The remaining sum is
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} {x-n\choose k}
= \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} {x-n\choose n-k}
\\ = [z^n] (1+z)^{x-n} \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} z^k
\\ = [z^n] (1+z)^{x-n} (1+z)^n
= [z^n] (1+z)^x = {x\choose n}.$$
This was factor number two and we may conclude.

What notation is $z^n^{x-n}$?

@Conreu [z^n]f(z) means coefficient of nth order term of f(z)
